# Match one or more specific pattern which is optional to repeat

Tags: javascript, java, regex

Looking for a `regex` that could work in both `Javascript` and `Java`.

The whole String should match as long as each capital alphabet follows by a `:Y`.

All following examples should match in full.

So Any Capital letter followed by a `:Y`. Like `A:Y`.
If there is more than 1 pair it is separated by a comma.

```
S:Y,P:Y,T:Y,A:Y
S:Y,P:Y,T:Y,A:Y,C:Y
S:Y,P:Y,T:Y,A:Y,C:Y,D:Y
A:Y
B:Y
D:Y,F:Y
```

All the following should never match. Cos 1 or more of them has `:N`.

```
S:Y,P:N,T:Y,A:Y
S:Y,P:Y,T:Y,A:Y,C:N
S:Y,P:Y,T:N,A:Y,C:N,D:Y
A:N
B:N
D:Y,F:N
```

I don't want to match in negative, like `:N` doesn't exist.

```
^(?!.*:N).+$
```

Looking for a way to match `:Y` instead.

Tried the following but this ends up with multiple mini matches which is not what I am looking for.

```
[SPTA:Y,]+
```

This could work. But again, this has multiple mini matches.

```
(?:[A-Z]:Y(?:,|$))+
```

Could I get some help with this pls.

Comment: You could use: `^([,]?([A-Z]:Y))*$` you may want to add a special case for the first match not to be prefixed by a comma

Comment: Is the one-but-last colon in the third line not a problem? (`,:D`)?

Comment: *"If there is more than 1 pair it is separated by a comma."*: is that a remark, or a **condition** for matching the line? What if there is a missing comma, or two consecutive commas, or a semicolon instead of a colon?

Comment: @trincot For your first comment, typo on my end, amended.

Comment: @trincot They are conditions, it must be a single comma that separates.

Comment: Alright. Would `^[A-Z]:Y(?:,[A-Z]:Y)*$` do what you want?

Comment: @trincot That fits perfectly!

Comment: You can also shorten it a bit by use of a word boundary: [`^(?:[A-Z]:Y,?\b)+$`](https://regex101.com/r/rEvaVy/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this regex:

```
^[A-Z]:Y(?:,[A-Z]:Y)*$
```

- `^`: Assert the we're at the start of the input
- `[A-Z]`: Match a capital English letter
- `:Y`: Math literally ":Y"
- `(?:   )*`: repeat the enclosed pattern 0 or more times
- `,`: a literal comma
- `$`: Assert we're at the end of the input.

Comment: ...or `^(?:(?:,|^|)[A-Z]:Y)+$`, but I prefer what you have.

Answer (score 1):

Just use this, as all are full lines, just anchor them to beggining or end

```
^[A-Z]:Y(,[A-Z]:Y)*$
```

- `^` asserts position at start of a line
- `[A-Z]` matches a single character in the range between `A` and `Z`
- `:Y` matches the characters `:Y` literally.
- 1st Capturing Group `(,[A-Z]:Y)*`. `*` matches the group between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible.

  - `,` matches the character `,`
  - `[A-Z]` matches a single character in the range between `A` and `Z`.
  - `:Y` matches the characters `:Y` literally.
- `$` asserts position at the end of a line.

This is: groups of one or more `[A-Z]:Y` separated by `,` and of arbitrary length.

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZiEnZF/1).